# How to set cabal flag from shell.nix for stack project?

Tags: haskell, cabal, haskell-stack, nix

By default I build my project without `nix`, and executable is linked statically. But when building with `nix`, I want to link it dynamically instead. So I added a switch to `myproj.cabal`:

```
flag dynamic
  description: Build only dynamic binaries
  default: False

executable RunMe
  ghc-options:         -O2 -Wall
  if !flag(dynamic)
    ghc-options: -optl-static -static
```

Now I can build the project with

```
stack --nix --nix-packages=zlib install --flag myproj:dynamic
```

To avoid passing command line options every time, I created `shell.nix`:

```
{ghc}:
with (import <nixpkgs> {});
haskell.lib.buildStackProject {
  inherit ghc;
  name = "myproj";
  buildInputs = [ zlib ];
}
```

Now, I don't know how to pass flag to cabal from nix file. Based on [`buildStackProject`](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/master/pkgs/development/haskell-modules/generic-stack-builder.nix) definition, I tried setting `buildPhase`, e.g.

```
haskell.lib.buildStackProject {
  ...
  buildPhase = "stack build --flag=myproj:dynamic";
}
```

but it doesn't seem to change anything. How can I pass the flag to cabal from the `nix` file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, the stack nix integration is rather backwards. It doesn't use nix to build your package (despite the very misleading`buildStackPackage`), just to create an environment with GHC and native dependencies. You have to use `stack` itself to build the project, and since `stack` will run `cabal`, it should still work with the flag. The stack nix integration will *not* generate a `.nix` file with the dependencies resolved by stack, so you can't build your project with `nix-build` and there's no point in entering `nix-shell`. You would have to use a tool like `stack2nix` or `stackage2nix` for that.

So to recap. The `shell.nix` above looks fine. Add this to your `stack.yaml`:

```
nix:
    shell-file: shell.nix
```

And build the project with stack:

```
stack --nix --flag myproj:dynamic
```

That should build the project with the flag as usual, but use GHC and zlib from `nix`.